# How to search efficiently given 1mil data in array of integers - ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a mtd to search through 1mil or more records (stored as an arraylist of integers in asc order) to check if the pass in empID belongs to one of the records stored.

Currently, i uses sequential search through for loop. How to make it more efficient/faster?

```
def exist?(id)
    for i in 0...$employee_list.length
        if $employee_list[i] == id # match!
            return true
        elsif $employee_list[i] > id # have already gone beyond the point where id should've been found
            return false
        end
    end

return false # cannot find id in the list
end
```

I also tried using hash as follows but still not fast enough.

```
hash = $employee_list.map{ |i | i}

if hash.include? id
    return true 
else
    return false
end
```

Comment: That's not how you build a hash. You're *calling* it a hash, but you're mapping an array to itself, returning an *identical* array.

Comment: PS: your `if/else` statement is an anti-pattern. Even if your hash code were fixed to create an actual hash, you should write `return hash.include?(id)`, or just `hash.include?(id)` (without the `return`). Testing a boolean result to decide which boolean value to return is a waste of your fingers/wrists, and a waste of space for someone reading or maintaining your code later.

Comment: PS If you want to test if a value is in a (smaller) array, use [`Array#include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F), like so: `def exist?(id); $employee_list.include?(id); end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Set`, unless you have proven that you cannot afford the memory:

```
# Do this just once
require 'set'
$employee_ids = Set.new $employee_list

# Do this each time you need to check
def exist?(id)
  $employee_ids.include?(id)
end
```

It will be nearly instantaneous, regardless of the number of ids you have.

Comment: however, im not exactly sure how set works though.. to make it run faster

Comment: Like a hash, a set performs a hashing algorithm on each value stored in it. When you ask if it has a value, it hashes that value and then checks the hash table to see if it's in there. This is always a constant time operation. Look up [Hash Tables](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for more details.

Comment: @Phrogz: Not quite always a constant time operation, but close enough that it usually doesn't matter. Every collision prolongs it.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use a `Set` instead of an `Array` (for space reasons), and if your `Array` is sorted, you can use [`Array#bsearch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) with a block that returns an integer (like `<=>`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
array.bsearch {|x| number <=> x }
```

This does a binary search on the array. The array MUST be sorted.

Note that the element `x` is to the right side of the spaceship operator!

Use the `ri` command to read more documentation on the `bsearch` method. The time complexity of binary search is `O(log n)`. Which is 20 steps only for an array of length 1 million.

Comment: OP mentioned that — "stored as an arraylist of integers in asc order"

Comment: wow, did not see it (howcome?...), I'm wrong - you're right. Deleting my answer since yours is the way to go here

Comment: if i use the hash like u provided, how do i check if my id matches any in the hash ? 
using if hash.include? id  ?

Comment: Just use `hash[number]` which either returns `true` or `nil` — PS, I removed the `zip` example, it was broken).

Comment: thanks.. i tried but i still got "Execution timed out" in my server (not fast enough)

Comment: how abt if i use the.array.bsearch, how do i check my id is inside?

Comment: See above `array.bsearch {|x| number <=> x }`